# OpenSSL BN_sub() can't do signed subtraction

Tags: c++, c, openssl, signed, bignum

I'm trying to perform subtraction using OpenSSL's `BN` functions. I am expecting a signed integer as the difference, but instead I get either the unsigned integer, or the integer overflows (or if neither I get the desired result).

Am I using the wrong `BN` function?

```
int big_num_subtract_example(vector<int> *arr, unsigned int mod, int seed_num) {
    BN_CTX *ctx;
    ctx = BN_CTX_new();

    BIGNUM *product = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *tmp = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *modulo = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *mod_result = BN_new();

    BN_set_word(product, seed_num);
    BN_set_word(modulo, mod);

    for (auto elem : arr) {

        BN_CTX_start(ctx);

        BN_set_word(tmp, elem);

        BN_mul(product, product, tmp, ctx);

        //Start of example
        BIGNUM *sub_one = BN_new();
        BIGNUM *sub_two = BN_new();

        BIGNUM *num_one = BN_new();
        BIGNUM *num_two = BN_new();

        BN_set_word(num_one, -7);
        BN_set_word(num_two, 11);

        BN_sub(sub_one, num_one, num_two);
        BN_sub(sub_two, num_two, num_one);

        cout << "sub_one: " << BN_get_word(sub_one) << "\n"; //18446744073709551598 expected -4
        cout << "sub_two: " << BN_get_word(sub_two) << "\n"; //18446744073709551598 expected 18

        BN_set_word(num_one, 7);
        BN_set_word(num_two, 11);

        BN_sub(sub_one, num_one, num_two);
        BN_sub(sub_two, num_two, num_one);

        cout << "sub_one: " << BN_get_word(sub_one) << "\n"; //4 expected -11
        cout << "sub_two: " << BN_get_word(sub_two) << "\n"; //4 
        //end of example


        //...
        //Code using the product from start of loop and result of subtraction...
        //...

        BN_CTX_end(ctx);

    }

    BN_clear_free(product);
    BN_clear_free(tmp);
    BN_clear_free(modulo);
    BN_clear_free(mod_result);
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

The [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/BN_sub.html) state:

> BN_sub() subtracts b from a and places the result in r (r=a-b). r may
>   be the same BIGNUM as a or b.

Comment: BN_get_word returns an unsigned integer. Maybe it is the get that generates issues,  see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/BN_get_word.html

Comment: What makes you think openssl bignums support negative values?

Comment: BN_set_word() and BN_get_word() both only support unsigned values.

Comment: @stark the `BN_set_negative()`, `BN_is_negative()` functions found here...: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/bn.html

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts Ah thanks! That makes much more sense.